# Script php stop without error messages

Tags: php, mysql

I want to input in a database some values from a txt files.
I have a loop who extract the data that i want, check if it don't already exist and else insert it.

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM SITE WHERE domain_site = '".$domain."'");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if ($res["nb"] == 0) {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO SITE (domain_site) VALUES ('".$domain."')");
}
```

I have see that in my DB, their is not all the values, so I add this line :

```
echo $domain."</br>";
```

and the output stop before the end of my file without reasons and error messages

PS : I have set these parameters in the top of my php

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
ini_set('memory_limit', '100M');
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Someone have an idea why my script stop or how to solve it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

`printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));`

This will print the error(if any from DataBase).

Comment: I forgot to say it, but the sql request work for the first lines, i got 145 values int my table.
I have try your line and their is nothing more than "Errormessage:".

Comment: How many records do you have in total, and are you sure that you have more than 145 unique records?

Comment: in total i got 260k lines in my txt file ( many double ) i don't know how many différents but I'm sure more than 145.
When i echo for each lines, i got about of 1k outputed lines.

Comment: You should also try to escape you values before passing it to the query, `$domain = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, addslashes($domain));`

Comment: I can try, but even it's only a domain name, their is no spécials characters, isn'it ?

Comment: yes you are right but its a good practice to always escape values before inserting them to DataBase even if you, yourself generating the data.

Comment: What's for ? how can I input my text file in this ?

Comment: just signup and create the necessary file and share the link

Comment: Even if it strange, this look like solve my problem ! Thank you.